# PowerShell and the -contains operator

Tags: powershell, operators, string-matching

Consider the following snippet:

```
"12-18" -Contains "-"
```

You’d think this evaluates to `true`, but it doesn't. This will evaluate to `false` instead. I’m not sure why this happens, but it does.

To avoid this, you can use this instead:

```
"12-18".Contains("-")
```

Now the expression will evaluate to true.

Why does the first code snippet behave like that? Is there something special about `-` that doesn't play nicely with `-Contains`? [The documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

The `-Contains` operator doesn't do substring comparisons and the match must be on a complete string and is used to search collections.

From the documentation you linked to:

> -Contains
>   Description: Containment operator. **Tells whether a collection of reference values includes a single test value.**

In the example you provided you're working with a collection containing just one string item.

If you read the documentation you linked to you'll see an example that demonstrates this behaviour:

Examples:

```
PS C:\> "abc", "def" -Contains "def"
True

PS C:\> "Windows", "PowerShell" -Contains "Shell"
False  #Not an exact match
```

I think what you want is the [`-Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#-match) operator:

```
"12-18" -Match "-"
```

Which returns `True`.

**Important:** As pointed out in the comments and in the [linked documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#-match), it should be noted that the `-Match` operator uses [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6) to perform text matching.

Comment: For completeness, while -Match may be a good match it uses regex. If one want a unambiguous string contains check one should do as the OP describes:
`"12-18".Contains("-")`

Comment: @8DH - very good catch :) . Having re-read the question I think I need to clarify the difference between the `Contains` powershell operator and the `.Contains()` _.NET_ `String` method.

Comment: As already mentioned in comment above, `-Match` uses regex. That means that the string parameter is a regex, not a normal string. For example, `"hello" -Match "."` will return true, because `"."` is a regex where a '.' will match any character. To check if a string contains a full stop: `"hello" -Match "\."` (returns false)

Comment: This is certainly a "false friend"! :)  The existence of "-contains" meaning "belonging to a list".

Answer (score 55):

`-Contains` is actually a collection operator. It is true if the collection contains the object. It is not limited to strings.

[`-match` and `-imatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) are regular expression string matchers, and set automatic variables to use with captures.

`-like`, `-ilike` are SQL-like matchers.

Answer (score 36):

You can use `like`:

```
"12-18" -like "*-*"
```

Or `split` for `contains`:

```
"12-18" -split "" -contains "-"
```

Answer (score 2):

- `like` is best, or at least easiest.
- `match` is used for regex comparisons.

Reference: *[About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)*