# PowerShell Variable Contains Specific Numbers

Tags: powershell

**Scenario**

When my variable (called $Numbers) contains 0, 1 **and** 2, it'll run anything under the first IF statement.  If my variable contains 0, 1, 2 **and** 3, it'll run the other IF statement.

**Issue**

I can't seem to get this working since it continuously runs the first IF statement (due to still containing 0, 1 and 2) but never skips this if it doesn't contain the number 3.

**Brief Code Example**

```
If ($Numbers -contains "*0,*" -and "*1,*" -and "*2,*") {

    Write-Host = "Does not contain 3"

}

Elseif ($Numbers -contains "*0,*" -and "*1,*" -and "*2,*" -and "*3,*") {

    Write-Host "Contains 3"

}
```

**Any guidance is appreciated.**

Comment: if `$Numbers` is a collection, drop the wildcards. If `$Numbers` is a string, use `match` io `contains`. In both cases, as Maarten said, reverse the statement.

Comment: I would really like to see how $numbers is populate or the exact contents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator/18877724#18877724

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test syntax is wrong.

`-Contains` is going to look for exact matches, not wildcard matches, plus each `-and` condition must be a standalone test, e.g.

```
If ($Numbers -contains 0 -and $Numbers -contains 1 -and $Numbers -contains 2)
```

"*1,*" or "*2,*" by themselves are non-null strings and will always evaluate to $true, absent any kind of comparison operation being applied to them.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the if statement, test for 0, 1, 2, 3 first, test for 0, 1, 2 in the `Elseif`. You should always test for the more specific situation first.