# Delete whole line in html file recursively with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to delete the "unwanted" class lines from an HTML file using power shell script

```
<a class="unwanted" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/of/url1" target="_blank">my_file_name1</a><br>
<a class="mylink" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/of/url2" target="_blank">my_file_name2</a><br>
<a class="unwanted" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/of/url3" target="_blank">my_file_name3</a><br>
```

Currently i'm replacing strings using this script

```
$s = "old string"
$r = "new string"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder" -Recurse -Filter *.html | % {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName) `
    | % { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($s), $r } `
    | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing lines is even easier than replacing them.  When outputting to `Set-Content`, simply omit the lines that you want removed.  You can do this with `Where-Object` in place of your `Foreach`.

Adapting your example:

```
$s = "unwanted regex"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder" -Recurse -Filter *.html | % {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName) `
    | where { $_ -notmatch $s } `
    | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

If you want literal matching instead of regex, substitute the where clause

```
where { -not $_.Contains($s) } `
```

Note this is using the .NET function `[String]::Contains()`, and not the PowerShell operator `-contains`, as [the latter doesn't work on strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator).

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, +1

Comment: I've used **.*unwanted** as regex

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question also with [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), I want to contribute a related answer.

`cmd.exe`/batch scripting does not understand HTML file format, but if your HTML file(s) look(s) like the sample data you provided (the `<a>` tag and the corresponding `</a>` tag are in a single line, and there is nothing else (than `<br>`)), the following command line could work for you -- supposing a HTML file to process is called `classes.html` and the modified data is to be written to file `classes_new.html`:

```
> "classes_new.html" findstr /V /I /L /C:"class=\"unwanted\"" "classes.html"
```

This only works if the string `class="unwanted"` occurs only in the `<a>` tags that need to be removed.

---

To process multiple files, the following batch script could be used, based on the above command line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "ARGS=%*"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%H in (!ARGS!) do (
    endlocal
    call :SUB "%%~H"
    setlocal
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B

:SUB file
if /I not "%~x1"==".html" if /I not "%~x1"==".htm" exit /B 1
findstr /V /I /L /C:"class=\"unwanted\"" "%~f1" | (> "%~f1" find /V "")
exit /B
```

The actual removal of lines is done in the sub-routine `:SUB`, unless then file name extension is something other than `.html` or `htm`. The main script loops through all the given command line arguments and calls `:SUB` for every single file. Note that this script does not create new files for the modified HTML contents, it **overwrites the given HTML files**.

Answer (score -1):

Try using multiline strings for your `$s` and `$r`. I tested with the HTML examples you posted as well and that worked fine.

```
$s = @"
old string
"@
$r = @"
new string
"@

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder" -Recurse -Filter *.html | % {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName) `
    | % { $_ -replace $s, $r } `
    | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```