# Retrieving second part of a line when first part matches exactly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I used the below steps to retrieve a string from file

```
$variable = 'abc@yahoo.com'
$test = $variable.split('@')[0];
$file = Get-Content C:\Temp\file1.txt | Where-Object { $_.Contains($test) }
$postPipePortion = $file | Foreach-Object {$_.Substring($_.IndexOf("|") + 1)}
```

This results in all lines that contain `$test` as a substring. I just want the result to contain only the lines that exactly matches `$test`.

For example, If a file contains

```
abc_def|hf#23$ 
abc|ohgvtre
```

I just want the text `ohgvtre`

Comment: I don't follow you.  Why bother splitting the string at all then?  Why not just search for 'abc@yahoo.com`?

Comment: @briantist Not a duplicate.  [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator) is about the operator, which doesn't work on characters in strings.  This one correctly uses the .NET `String.Contains` method to compare substrings.  The problem is that OP wants an exact match, not a substring match, so both forms of "contains" are wrong.

Comment: @RyanBemrose you're right; I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you probably want to use [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849891.aspx) instead of `Get-Content`:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\file1.txt' -Delimiter '|' -Header 'foo', 'bar' |
  Where-Object { $_.foo -eq $test } |
  Select-Object -Expand bar
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the exact matching, you should be testing for equality (`-eq`) rather than substring (`.Contains()`).  Also, there is no need to parse the data multiple times.  Here is your code, rewritten to to operate in one pass over the data using the `-split` operator.

```
$variable = 'abc@yahoo.com'
$test = $variable.split('@')[0];

$postPipePortion = (

  # Iterate once over the lines in file1.txt
  Get-Content C:\Temp\file1.txt | foreach {

    # Split the string, keeping both parts in separate variables.
    # Note the backslash - the argument to the -split operator is a regex
    $first, $second = ($_ -split '\|')

    # When the first half matches, output the second half.
    if ($first -eq $test) {
      $second
    }
  }
)
```