# Contains operator not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have never got the `-contains` operator to work in Powershell I don't know why.

Here's an example of where it isn't working. I use `-like` in its place but I'd love it if you could tell me why this isn't working.

```
PS HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion> (gp . P*).ProductName
Windows 10 Enterprise

PS HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion> (gp . P*).ProductName -contains "Windows"
False

PS HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion> (gp . P*).ProductName | gm | select TypeName | Get-Unique

TypeName     
--------     
System.String
```

Comment: you're looking for `-match 'Windows'` or `-like '*Windows*'`, contains is for arrays only.

Comment: The `-match` operator, as far as I understand, is for working with regular expressions, which include the smaller subset of wildcards, so that will work as well. But if I wanted to just use the `contains` operator properly, how would I do that? My question is not *how do I do this?* but rather *why does this never work for me and what am I doing wrong with this operator here?* There are a 100 ways to do the thing. I could just call `"The string Value".Contains()` from the .NET Base Class Library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-contains` operator is not a string operator, but a *collection containment* operator:

```
'a','b','c' -contains 'b' # correct use of -contains against collection
```

From the [`about_Comparison_Operators` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators):

```
Type         Operator      Description
Containment  -contains     Returns true when reference value contained in a collection
             -notcontains  Returns true when reference value not contained in a collection
             -in           Returns true when test value contained in a collection
             -notin        Returns true when test value not contained in a collection
```

---

Usually you would use the `-like` string operator in PowerShell, which supports Windows-style wildcard matching (`*` for any number of any characters, `?` for exactly one of any character, `[abcdef]` for one of a character set):

```
'abc' -like '*b*' # $true
'abc' -like 'a*' # $true
```

Another alternative is the `-match` operator:

```
'abc' -match 'b' # $true
'abc' -match '^a' # $true
```

For verbatim substring matching, you would want to escape any input pattern, since `-match` is a regex operator:

```
'abc.e' -match [regex]::Escape('c.e')
```

---

An alternative is to use the [`String.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
'abc'.Contains('b') # $true
```

With the caveat that, unlike powershell string operators, it's case-sensitive.

---

[`String.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is yet another alternative, this one allows you to override the default case-sensitivity:

```
'ABC'.IndexOf('b', [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) -ge 0
```

`IndexOf()` returns `-1` if the substring is not found, so any non-negative return value can be interpreted as having found the substring.

Comment: Ah! As I suspected. Your first line answered my question. Thank you. I should make some time for a thorough reading of the documentation.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 There's a lot of good stuff in the `about_*` help topics, I updated the answer with a table of containment operators from the `about_Comparison_Operators` document

Comment: That's right. I'm aware of them, @Mathias. Just haven't made the time to read through all of it carefully yet.

Answer (score 2):

The '-contains' operator is best used for comparison to lists or arrays, e.g.

```
$list = @("server1","server2","server3")
if ($list -contains "server2"){"True"}
else {"False"}
```

output:

```
True
```

---

I'd suggest using '-match' instead for string comparisons:

```
$str = "windows"
if ($str -match "win") {"`$str contains 'win'"}
if ($str -match "^win") {"`$str starts with 'win'"}
if ($str -match "win$") {"`$str ends with 'win'"} else {"`$str does not end with 'win'"}
if ($str -match "ows$") {"`$str ends with 'ows'"}
```

output:

```
$str contains 'win'
$str starts with 'win'
$str does not end with 'win'
$str ends with 'ows'
```