# -contains or -match several values

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have to filter my results by certain strings and tried to do it with `-match` and `-contains`.

`-match` works if I have just one value to filter, but not with an array.

`-contains` neither works with one string, nor with a string array.

Why isn't it working with several values? Especially the `-contains`. Or is there another easy way to solve it?

```
$Folder = 'C:\Test'

$filterArray =  @('2017-05', '2017-08')
$filter =  '2017-05'

## test with -MATCH

## working with one match string
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt |
    Where { $_.FullName -match $filter } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
## NOT working with match string array - no results
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt |
    Where { $_.FullName -match $filterArray } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }

## test with -CONTAINS
## NOT working with one contains string - no results
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt |
    Where { $_.FullName -contains $filter } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
## NOT working with contains string array- no results
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt |
    Where { $_.FullName -contains $filterArray } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Related (difference between `-Contains` (collection operator), `-match` /`-imatch` (regular expression matching), and `-like` / `-ilike` (SQL-like matching)): *[PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator/18877950#18877950)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an array as the second operand for the `-match` or `-contains` operators doesn't work. There are basically two approaches you could take:

- Build a regular expression from the array and use that with the `-match` operator:

  ```
  $pattern = @($filterArray | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
  ... | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match $pattern }
  ```

This is the preferred approach.

- Use a nested `Where-Object` filter and the `String.Contains()` method:

  ```
  ... | Where-Object {
      $f = $_.FullName
      $filterArray | Where-Object { $f.Contains($_) }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't it working with several values?

Because these operators were designed to test against a single argument, plain and simple.

The ability to match against multiple arguments in a single operation would beg the question: "Does the input need to satisfy *all* or *any* of the argument conditions"?

---

If you want to test for a match against *any* of an array of regex patterns, you can construct a single pattern from them using a non-capturing group, like so:

```
$filterPattern = '(?:{0})' -f ($filterArray -join '|')
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where {$_.FullName -match $filterPattern} | ForEach-Object{ $_.FullName }
```

You can also drop the `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object` loop completely, since PowerShell 3.0 supports property enumeration:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *.txt).FullName -match $filterPattern
```

Comment: Why the non-capturing group? Simply joining the strings should work as well. I would recommend escaping the individual strings, though.

Comment: You should always escape string when you built regular expressions programmatically. `$filterPattern = '(?:{0})' -f (($filterArray |% { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')`