# Fuzzy string match in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, fuzzy-search

How can I do fuzzy string matching within PowerShell scripts?

I have different sets of names of people scraped from different sources and have them stored in an array. When I add a new name, I like to compare the name with existing name and if they fuzzily matches, I like to consider them to be the same. For example, with data set of:

```
@("George Herbert Walker Bush",
  "Barbara Pierce Bush",
  "George Walker Bush",
  "John Ellis (Jeb) Bush"  )
```

I like to see following outputs from the given input:

```
"Barbara Bush" -> @("Barbara Pierce Bush")
"George Takei" -> @("")
"George Bush"  -> @("George Herbert Walker Bush","George Walker Bush")
```

At minimum, I like to see matching to be case insensitive, and also flexible enough to handle some level of misspelling if possible.

As far as I can tell, standard libraries does not provide such functionalities. Is there an easy-to-install module which can accomplish this?

Comment: If it was just matching strings inside other strings, [the -Match operator would do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator/18877724#18877724).

Comment: Or the [`-like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Searching at [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=fuzzy&x=0&y=0) with term "fuzzy", I found this package: [Communary.PASM](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.PASM).

It can be simply installed with:

```
PS> Install-Package Communary.PASM
```

The project is found [here](https://github.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM) in GitHub.  I simply looked at [this examples file](https://github.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/blob/master/Tests/examples.ps1) for reference.

Here is my examples:

```
$colors = @("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Sky Blue" )

PS> $colors | Select-FuzzyString Red

Score Result
----- ------   
  300 Red
```

This is a perfect match, with 100 max score for each characters.

```
PS> $colors | Select-FuzzyString gren

Score Result
----- ------
  295 Green
```

It tolerate a little missing characters.

```
PS> $colors | Select-FuzzyString blue

Score Result  
----- ------     
  400 Blue       
  376 Sky Blue
```

Multiple values can be returned with different scores.

```
PS> $colors | Select-FuzzyString vioret

# No output
```

But it does not tolerate a little bit of misspell.  Then I also tried `Select-ApproximateString`:

```
PS> $colors | Select-ApproximateString vioret
Violet
```

This has different API that it only returns a single match or nothing.  Also it may not return anything when `Select-FuzzyString` does.

This was tested with PowerShell Core v6.0.0-beta.9 on MacOS and Communary.PASM 1.0.43.

Comment: Powershell 7 has some kind of fuzzy match with misspelled commands.  I wonder if there's a way to apply it generally.