# .contains() vs -contains, one returns true, other returns false

Tags: powershell

I have a Hash Table like this:

```
$Path = @{
    "BM"    = "\\srv\xy"
    "BB4-L" = "\\srv\xy"
    "BB4-R" = "\\srv\xy"
    "HSB"   = "\\srv\xy"
    "IB"    = "\\srv\xy"
    "LM1"   = "\\srv\xy"
    "LM2"   = "\\srv\xy"
    "sis"   = "\\srv\xy"
}
```

my `$env:username` is sis. Why does `.contains()` and `-contains` something different?

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\Functions> $Path -contains $env:username
False

PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\Functions> $Path.contains($env:username)
True
```

I always like to go with the PowerShell Syntax if possible, but I can't in this case, since `-contains` would return false.

How are `.contains()` and `-contains` different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MS documentation:

```
-Contains
      Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference
      values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
      only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.
```

`.Contains()` Method is one of the methods of a `String` object that supports substring hence why you get
`True` when you run `$Path.Contains($env:username)`

Answer (score 2):

`$Path` is a `System.Collections.Hashtable`. You can also read in documentation that:

> When the test value is a collection, the Contains operator uses
>   reference equality. It returns TRUE only when one of the reference
>   values is the same instance of the test value object.

Each item in hashtable is `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`. You are comparing it to `string`. Since types do not match, references do not match as well. `Contains(System.Object key)` and `ContainsKey(System.Object key)` use keys to test. To be consistent in comparisons you should write:

```
$Path.Keys -contains $env:username
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work by changing from hashtable.containskey to -contains. In the following code snippit, i commented our the line containing .containsKey($UserIDFromAD) and added the line containing $UserIDsFromFile.keys -contains $UserIDFromAD. The code now works as expected.

So, whats the difference between .containskey and -contains?

```
#if ($UserIDsFromFile.containsKey($UserIDFromAD)){ #If the UserID is in Yesterdays list ignore it.
if ($UserIDsFromFile.keys -contains $UserIDFromAD){ #If the UserID is in Yesterdays list ignore it.
```