# How to match a string in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, match

I'm trying to match a string in PowerShell, but I can't get True.

```
"one.two" -match "One Two"
False
```

Ok, maybe I gave too limited information of my problem.

So here is a bit more information. I have this code:

```
$userRoles = @('User', 'Customer Support');
$adGroups = @('ad.group.user', 'ad.group.customer.admin');
$userRoleToAdGroup = @{};
foreach ($userRole in $userRoles) {
    $adGroupsMatch = @($adGroups -match "$userRole")
    $userRoleToAdGroup.Add($userRole, $adGroupsMatch)
}
$userRoleToAdGroup
```

And the output value is empty for "Customer Support".

Comment: From the limited info you give, my guess is that you have the strings the wrong way around.  Try: `"One Two" -match "one.two"`.  The string to test should appear on the left and the regex pattern on the right.

Comment: I narrowed down my problem to very simple match. Yes, the way around it works, but it doesn't work in this case: "here.is.some.text" -match "Some Text".

Comment: As @boxdog tried to explain, the regex pattern to test **with** should be on the right-hand side of the `-match` operator. Your commented example uses a literal string (with a space) which is not a regex pattern at all.

Comment: The title is too general. Thus this question comes up in search engine results for queries like *"PowerShell fuzzy string match"*. A more canonical question is: *[PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator/18877950#18877950)*  (the answer covers the difference between `-Contains` (for collections), `-match` / `-imatch` (regular expression string matching), and `-like`, `-ilike` (SQL-like matching))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve but you should take a look at PowerShell syntax and the -match operator.

Matching a role name like `Customer Support` is really just matching the same exact string when using regex. One way to make this match *like* a wildcard would be

```
$String = "Customer Support"
$MatchString = "($($String -replace '\s+', '|'))"
'ad.group.customer.admin' -match $MatchString
True
```

This code is spliting any spaces in `$String` and combines them in a legit regex query `"(Customer|Support)"`.

**NOTE**

This code will match any string with the word "customer" and / or "support" in it.

```
'ad.group.user.support' -match $MatchString
True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here the space between "One" and "Two" will match literally "One Two". If you want to match any character between them use:

```
"one.two" -match "One.Two"
```

Here in Regex `.` means any character. Or you can append

```
* = 0 or more instances of previous charcter
+ = 1 or more instances of previous charcter
? = 0 or 1 instances of previous charcter
\w = match any word
\d = match any digit
\s = match any whitespace
{n,m} = match n to m instances of previous charcter
```