# How to filter objects using -notcontains in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter objects that don't contain the string `"C: \ Windows"` in their path but the filtering isn't working well with `$_.PathName` parameter.

```
function unquotedPath {
    $unquotedPaths = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.StartMode -eq "Auto"  -and $_.PathName -notcontains "C:\WINDOWS\"} | Select-Object -Property Name,DisplayName,PathName,StartMode | Out-String
    foreach ($unquotedPath in $unquotedPaths) {
        Write-Host $unquotedPath -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    
}
```

Comment: -notcontains is a collection operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator

Comment: and `| Out-String` makes it a single string object...

Comment: Im using Out-String to get a better output format it doesn't change the filtering anyways

Comment: In short: [`-contains` / `-notcontains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) are _collection operators_: they test if the LHS object is _equal in full_ to at least one element of the RHS collection. They are not to be confused with the  `.Contains()` .NET _method_ for _substring matching_.  While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for _literal_ substring matching, you can use `-like` with _wildcard expressions_ or `-match` with _regular expressions_, both of which are case-_insensitive_.

Comment: To close the tangent re `Out-String`: What @iRon is trying to say is that `$unquotedPaths` will receive a _single_ (multi-line) output string across all filtered objects, so your foreach` loop will be entered (at most) _once_. Omitting the loop and using `Write-Host $unquotedPaths -ForegroundColor Green` instead would have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

-notcontains is a collection operator.
See helpful post at: [PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator)

You can use:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.StartMode -eq "Auto" -and !$_.PathName.Contains('C:\WINDOWS\')}
```

Comment: The link is helpful - though I think submitting it as part of a duplicate close vote would have sufficed. Note that `.Contains()` - unlike PowerShell's operators - is case-_sensitive_; _invariably_ so in Windows PowerShell, and _by default_ in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

Comment: @mklement0 - considered that, noted, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `-notcontains`, use `-notlike`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.StartMode -eq "Auto"  -and $_.PathName -notlike "*C:\WINDOWS\*"}
```

.. or `-notmatch`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.StartMode -eq "Auto"  -and $_.PathName -notmatch "^.*C:\\WINDOWS\\"}
```

---

`-notcontains` is for checking whether the right hand argument (an object) matches one of the elements in the left side argument (a set). See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-contains-and--notcontains).

`-notlike` is for checking whether the element does not match a specific pattern. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators).

`-notmatch` is like `-notlike` but allows for regex expressions, so its more powerful. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators).